# wrong lemmatizing using nltk "python 3.7.4"

Tags: nltk, python-3.7, lemmatization

I'm using nltk lemmatizer and I get wrong result everytime !!

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> print(WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize('loved'))
loved
>>> print(WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize('creating'))
creating
```

the output is 'loved'/ 'creating'.. and it should be 'love' / 'create'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Wordnet's lemmatizer defaults the part-of-speech to Noun, so you need to tell it you're lemmatizing a Verb.

```
print(WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize('loved', pos='v'))
love
print(WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize('creating', pos='v'))
create
```

Any lemmatizer you use will need to know the part-of-speech so it knows what rules to apply.  While the two words you have are always verbs, lots of words can be both.  For instance, the word "painting" can be a noun or a verb.  The lemma of the verb "painting" (ie.. I am painting) is "paint". 
 If you use "painting" as a noun (ie.. A painting), "painting" is the lemma since it's the singular form of the noun.

In general, NLTK/Wordnet is not terribly accurate, especially for words not in its word list.  I was unhappy with the performance of the available lemmatizers so I created me own.  See [Lemminflect](https://github.com/bjascob/LemmInflect).  The main Readme page also has a comparison of a few common lemmatizers if you don't want to use that one.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly.. and when I use lemmatizer for a whole text which contains verbs, nouns, adjs... what should I do ??

Comment: You need to tag it first, then pass the tag to the lemmatizer (you'll have to translate the tag to simple "N", "V" or "A").  Take a look at https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html.  I would recommend Spacy over NLTK.  They make it really easy to do this.